# Mathematical foundations to justify the "existence" and appropriateness of using prior distributions?

Tags: bayesian, prior

I claim that there is no a priori reason I should use a probability distribution to express uncertainty about models, claims or parameters.

Apparently, (some) Bayesians disagree with that, as they require us to use prior distributions.

What are the mathematical justifications for using probability to express *all* types of uncertainties? Can you explain this in very simple terms?

The whole Bayesian philosophy seems like a pretty fragile castle, without a very strong justification for this.

Comment: Would you care to justify some of your claims?  Without any rationale behind them, you're asking for Bayesians to defend their position without knowing the arguments against them.

Comment: @DemetriPananos logically, my claims should have no bearing on the mathematical justification for prior distributions... the discipline should have these foundations regardless of what I claim. but if you want some justification, I can give you one: I have no quantifiable probabilistic belief about whether there exists a god or not.

Comment: My take on this is: As every mathematical modelling, Bayesian statistics when connected to the real world outside mathematics starts from some assumptions that cannot be proved mathematically. The reason is just that the real world is not all mathematics. Whenever you use mathematics to find something out about the real world, you have to live with that.

Comment: @Lewian there must be some mathematical foundations, your answer to the other question were part of that I think.

Comment: "There must be" ... why?

Comment: To be more precise, there are mathematical foundations that prove some assumptions from some other assumptions that one then cannot prove but needs to assume... You can't leave mathematics without leaving mathematics.

Comment: Frequentist statistics also place distributions on observed parameters. For example: by the CLT $\bar{x}$ follows a normal distribution centered at $\mu$ with a variance based on the number of samples taken. Bayes is built on probability theory, in order to do math, you have to quantify uncertainty somehow.

Comment: @RonJohnson There’s a huge difference between Bayesians putting a prior on $\mu$ and frequentists proving that the sampling distribution of a test statistic has a particular distribution.

Comment: @bayesian_newbie to avoid religion wars, can you think of a more everyday, non god related example?

Comment: @fblundun the example doesn't matter, this is just an illustration. I want first principles, not examples.

Comment: Let’s be very clear about your question. Is it “why do we choose probabilities as how we express uncertainty”, or “why do we express uncertainty about models and parameters”?

Comment: @bayesian_newbie this example may help. Suppose you refuse to put a prior on the proposition "the proposed new medicine X is an effective treatment of illness Y". The medicine is then tested on millions of patients, and they all recover. At this point, Bayes' Theorem would tell me that the proposition is probably true. Would you believe the proposition is probably true? If so, how could you justify that without saying that every successful treatment makes you think the proposition is slightly more likely to be true?

Comment: @AryaMcCarthy the question is: what are the mathematical foundations for expression uncertainty about model and parameters in terms of probabilities?

Comment: @fblundun I could say that without attaching a probability to the proposition.

Comment: @bayesian_newbie but you would still be putting the probability of the proposition in a range: the range (0.5, 1]. How many successful treatments does it take for you to go from having no prior at all for the proposition to being willing to say that its probability is in a range which is a strict subset of (0, 1]?

Comment: @fblundun if you want to elaborate your arguments in an answer, that would be great. We can't be discussing this in the comments.